# git clone:command not found

Tags: git

I want to install something. as I am running a command on my Linux is m getting this error. What should i do?

git clone https://iffgit.fz-juelich.de/fleur/fleur.git

If 'git' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
cnf git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 4):

Do you have `git` installed?

You can check that by opening your terminal and typing:

`apt policy git`

If it shows `Installed: (none)`, it means `git` isn't installed. You can install it by typing:

`sudo apt install git`

After installing it you can clone the repository.

Comment: Can also use `apt list git`. Easy for new users. Either it says `[installed]` or doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `bionic-updates` and the security repository enabled in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` then you will be able to install git through `sudo apt install git`

Answer (score -1):

u need to install git first

If you’re on a Debian-based distribution, such as Ubuntu, try apt:

```
$ sudo apt install git-all
```